# Examples of monotone functions where "number" of points of discontinuity is infinite

Tags: proof-verification, examples-counterexamples

We know that if $f:D(\subseteq \mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ be a monotone function and if $A$ be the set of points of discontinuity of $F$ then $\left\lvert A \right\rvert$ is [countable](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDQQFjAEahUKEwjs1-GwyuLHAhWICo4KHdJyCqE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCountable_set&usg=AFQjCNGIuDSm65tqMJVIOr1tAG8C3_LqTA). Where $\left\lvert A \right\rvert$ denotes the cardinality of $A$.

My question is,

> If $D=[a,b]$ then does there exist any function for which $\left\lvert A \right\rvert=\aleph_0$ ?

---

Actually the question arose when I attempted to prove that $\left\lvert A \right\rvert$ is countable. Let me briefly discuss the argument.

**Proof (certainly wrong in view of the comment below but can't find the flaw in the following argument)**

> Assume that $\left\lvert A \right\rvert$ is *infinite*. Then consider the quantity $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0+}f(x)-\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0-}f(x)$$for all $x_0\in A$. Now consider, $$B=\left\{\left\lvert\lim_{x\to x_0+}f(x)-\lim_{x\to x_0-}f(x)\right\rvert\mid x_0\in A\right\}$$Note that $B$ is bounded and $B\ne \emptyset$. So, $\sup B$ exists. Now define, $$\sup B\ge d_n> \dfrac{(n-1)\sup B}{n}$$ where $d_n\in B\setminus \{d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_{n-1}\}$
>
> Then the series $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty d_i$ diverges.

My conclusion followed from this argument.

Comment: Sure. For any countable set $S$, there is a monotonic function whose set of discontinuity is precisely $S$. If $S$ is finite, how do you construct such a function? Can you modify the construction to work for infinite $S$?

Comment: You are assuming that for any $c$ there exists an infinite sequence of discontinuities $d_n$ with jumps of at least $c(\sup B)$. This isn't necessarily true. What if, for instance, there was a jump of $1$, a jump of $\frac{1}2$, a jump of $\frac{1}4$, a jump of $\frac{1}8$, and so on?

Comment: Some positive constant. Essentially, your mistake seems to be that you thought the supremum is not attained. In fact, when the domain is $[a,b]$, the jumps give a sequence converging to $0$. You can arrange them so that $d_0 \geqslant d_1 \geqslant d_2 \geqslant \dotsc \geqslant d_n \geqslant d_{n+1} \geqslant \dotsc$.

Comment: @MiloBrandt: Let me elaborate on this matter. Since $\sup B$ exists, I construct a sequence $(d_n)_{n\ge1}$ by taking $\varepsilon=\frac{\sup B}{n}$. Can you say where is the mistake in this argument?

Comment: @DanielFischer: If supremum is attained infinitely many times then we simply take $(d_n)_{n\ge1}$ to be a constant sequence where $d_n=\sup B$. Otherwise, the supremum is attained finitely many times and we discard those elements from $B$ and form a new set $B'$. To this $B'$ we apply the same argument.

Comment: Unless the supremum is $0$ - and your function is continuous - it can be attained only finitely many times. Let's for simplicity assume each jump height occurs only once. Then you have a strictly decreasing sequence of jump heights. No problem. The condition that you can have these jumps is that $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty d_n < +\infty.$$ (If the domain is not a compact interval, you can also have a sequence of jumps with infinite sum.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me answer by first constructing a non-decreasing function $[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ with a discontinuity at every point $2^{-n}$ for $n>0$. In particular, set $f(x)=1$ for every $x\in (\frac{1}2,1]$ and say $f(x)=\frac{f(2x)}2$ for every $x\in [0,1]$. This defines a function with infinitely many discontinuities with the following self-similar graph:
$\hskip1.5in$[image]
One could also write this $f$ in closed form as $f(x)=2^{\lfloor\log_2(x)\rfloor}$. One could also consider the function $g(x)=f(x)+x$ if one desires a strictly increasing function with the same property.

Now, let us examine why your proof does not properly handle this case. The set $B$ is precisely:
$$B=\{2^{-n}:n>0\}\cup \{0\}$$
and satisfies
$$\sum_{b\in B}b=1$$
which immediately is a problem for your argument. Your argument correctly takes that there exists a $b\in B$ in any open interval around $\sup B$, but it incorrectly assumes these to be distinct. In this particular instance, $\sup B$ is the *maximum* of $B$ and is isolated from other points (rather than situation you seem to be imagining, where $\sup B$ is not in $B$, but rather is an accumulation point of $B$).

Comment: So if $\sup B$ is an accumulation point of $B$ then the argument works?

Comment: @user170039 Yeah. We could trim down your argument if we assumed $\sup B$ was an accumulation point, though - for instance, you could use $\frac{\sup B}2$ (or any $c<\sup B$) instead of $\frac{(n-1)\sup B}{n}$ since we really need "bounded below" not "converging to $\sup B$"

Answer (score 1):

- Take the graphic of any function you like, which is both continuous and monotonous over a finite interval of your choice $[a,~b]$.
- Map said interval to $[0,1]$ using $x\mapsto\dfrac{x-a}{b-a}$.
- Divide the new interval $[0,1]$ into an infinite number of subintervals of the form $\bigg(\dfrac1{n+1},\dfrac1n\bigg]$.
- Let the graphic on $\bigg(\dfrac12,1\bigg]$ untouched, and move the graphic on $\bigg[0,\dfrac12\bigg]$ upwards by $\dfrac1{2^2}$, if the function is descending, or downwards by $\dfrac1{2^2}$, if it's ascending.
- Similarly for $\bigg(\dfrac13,\dfrac12\bigg]$ and $\bigg[0,\dfrac13\bigg]$, leaving the former untouched, and translating the latter vertically by $\dfrac1{3^2}$, etc.
- I intentionally chose the quantum of translation $\dfrac1{n^2}$ instead of just $\dfrac1n$, because I wanted to avoid follow up questions of the form: *But then the value in $0$ will tend towards $\pm\infty$, since the harmonic series diverges, thus rendering the length of the function's value domain infinite. How could we avoid that, so that both its definition domain and image domain are finite ?*

Hope this helps!